Word order placement of prefix, mit, in this sentence
I think the sentence should read,"Ich durfte ihn  an den Strand mitnehmen. But I found, "Ich durfte ihn mit an den Strand nehmen."

"Mit" is not a preposition here, at least it is different from the construction "go to the beach with somebody". The handbook Fleischer & Barz, Wortbildung der deutschen Gegenwartssprache, 2012 ed. lists "mit" under verbal particles, subgroup "adverbial particles" (p. 212), but also mentions a possible classification as a prepositional particle. But still, it is mainly a particle. And it is not a prefix in the precise sense of the word.
A peculiarity is that "mit" is more loosely attached to the verb than other particles, also because it can give rise to formations with two particles: "mit-ein-beziehen" (and additionally, the base is a prefixed verb!). When you separate these, all parts are written separately: "bezieht es mit ein".
Janka's example "mit an den Strand mitnehmen" is interesting; I first thought it sounds odd, but Google has 280 hits of that exact phrase. In a way, this doubling of a particle is typical of prepositions (like "in den Hafen einfahren"). I am still sceptical whether you can classify "mit" as the head of a prepositional phrase, for it looks more like a modifier of another preposition in constructions like "eine Fahrt [mit an den Strand]" (if this is good, the basic structure is "Fahrt + an"). Or: "etwas mit in die Wand einbauen" ("in" depends on "bauen", "mit" just comes along).
On the other hand, the presence of "mit" somewhere else in the clause licenses the use of the verb "nehmen", which would be odd in isolation, cf.: "den Hund mit ins Restaurant nehmen" but not ?? "den Hund ins Restaurant nehmen". So in some sense, you always make reference to a particle verb "mitnehmen", even when there is no contact between the two. It's an interesting intermediate case of verbal particle and... well, something else.


Ich durfte ihn an den Strand mitnehmen.
Ich durfte ihn mit an den Strand nehmen.

Both are okay. There's even a third option:

Ich durfte ihn mit an den Strand mitnehmen.

The preposition mit and the prefix mit are a bit tricky in that regard. All variants mean the same. The latter one is a hypercorrection though.
